# For through html elements and appending only appends to last element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, for-loop, append

I have a text input and on focusout, I have couple of select elements which I want to fill with the text field's value.

And I have bunch of select tags with 'NameSelect' class

```
$('.textField').focusout(function() { 
   var name = $(this).val();

   var NameOption = $('<option>', { value: name, text: name, attrid: '1'});

   var selects = $('#mainForm').find('.NameSelect');

   $(selects).each(function(i, obj) {
       console.log($(obj));  // it seems to get the right select
       $(obj).append(NameOption);
   })
}
```

However, when I do that, even though the selects get all the right elements and for loop for the right count, it only appends the option input to the latest object, not all of them.

What am I missing here?

Comment: `selects` is already a jQuery object. So why do you do `$(selects)..`?

Comment: As you have set it to a var it is just moving that one around (it has only created one dom element) - you would need to just append `$('<option>', { value: name, text: name, attrid: '1'})` in the each loop or put the var in the each loop (so that it creates a new var / element each time)

Comment: @hindmost ye, i missed that. poor practice. but it doesnt change anything at all

Comment: @Pete So I need to move `var option` inside the for loop?

Comment: Yes, that should work - but I think Rory's solution is nicer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is because `NameOption` holds a reference to the `option`, hence if you `append()` it multiple times it will move between each parent element.

To fix this you can either `clone()` the element when you append it:

```
selects.append(NameOption.clone());
```

Or you could just provide `append()` with a string to create a new element each time it's called:

```
$('.textField').focusout(function() { 
   var name = $(this).val();
   $('#mainForm').find('.NameSelect').append('<option value="' + name + '" attrid="1">' + name + '</option>');
   })
});
```

Note that in both cases the `each()` is not required.